# Syntax for invoking multiple methods of an anonymous class in Java?

Tags: java, documentation, anonymous-class

```
Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(
                        getApplicationContext())
                    .setTicker(tickerText)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(mContentIntent)
                    .setSound(soundURI)
                    .setVibrate(mVibratePattern)
                    .setContent(mContentView);
```

invokes multiple methods on the anonymous[--correction: it's NOT anonymous--] class. On each line it starts with `.<method name>`.  Where is the official Java documentation on this?  I'm hoping there is a page on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/ that explains it.

PS. I just learned this is called "method chaining".  So where is the official Java documentation, if any, on this concept?

Comment: That could have been written in one line. Are you asking about the method chaining pattern?

Comment: That's nothing more than method chaining, a pattern that requires each method to be written so that it returns the object that is calling it, `return this;`. I see no anonymous class in your code above. The documentation for this is nothing more than the documentation for calling any and all methods. What exactly is your question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> So where is the official Java documentation, if any, on this concept?

If your method returns an object, you can call another method on the returned object, simple as that. All of the methods above return `this`, and so if method1, method2, and method3 all return `this` you can do this:

```
MyClass myVar = new MyClass().method1().method2().method3();
```

which is the same as:

```
MyClass myVar = new MyClass();
myVar.method1();
myVar.method2();
myVar.method3();
```

The documentation for Java method invocation can be found in the JLS Section 15.12.

Comment: `All of the methods above return this` or some other object.